# $ \mathbb{F} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:Ax=b\}= \mathbb{F}_r=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}:A^{(r)}x=b^{(r)}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-programming

Show that these two sets are equal.

$A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix of rank $r$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

$A^{(r)}$ denotes an $r\times n$ matrix with $r$ linearly independent rows of $A$ and $b^{(r)}$ is the corresponding $r$ vector.

I conceptually get this I think but I am having trouble getting started.

I know that if $x$ satisfies $Ax=b$ then $x$ will satisfy and subset of rows of $A$ so we can "discard" rows until we get to $r$ linearly independent rows.

That shows ones half of the inclusion.

I am not sure however if I am missing something with that statement and having trouble putting it into a rigorous argument.

Answer (score 1):

Is this true?

What is A is a $2\times 2$ matrix, and the first row of $A$ is $[1,1]$, and the second row of $A$ is $[0,0]$, and also $b = [1,1]^T$. Then $Ax=b$ has no solutions.

But the rank of $A$ is 1, and $A^{(r)}$ is the $1\times 2$ matrix $[1,1]$, and the equation $A^{(r)}x = 1$ does have solutions.

Comment: Both sets have the condition that $x$ such that $Ax=b$. Not considering inconsistent systems.